# Azure metric alert wrongly fired below threshold value

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-monitoring

I have a stateful metric alert which triggers a logic app when the maximum count of a dead-letter queue/topic is greater than 5
(this is a standard metric alert, not a custom one)

The alert is configured with:

- Evaluation frequency 5min
- Aggregation timeframe 5min

### Alert overview:

[image]

[image: Alert Logic]

### Problem

Azure monitor executes the action group and triggers the logic app even when the condition is NOT met. Navigating to the Logic app and inspecting the http trigger's payload:

[image]

I've even seen values of `metricValue: 0` why would that be the case?